# How to order a list using collect_list in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Say I have these two snippets of code:

Snippet 1:

```
db.select("ids", "names", "creation_date")
```

Snippet 2 (following snippet 1):

```
db.groupBy("ids")
  .agg(collect_list("names") as "alias")
  .select("ids", "alias")
```

My goal is to have my list return the output with the names in the youngest to oldest using the `creation_date`, which is a timestamp.

For example, if I had this db:

```
{"ids": 123, "names": Jack, "creation_date": 2022-07-07}  
{"ids": 123, "names": Mike, "creation_date": 2022-07-22}  
{"ids": 123, "names": Lust, "creation_date": 2022-05-01}
```

After passing it through the 2 snippets of code, I want the return to be

```
{"ids": 123, "items": [Mike, Jack, Lust]}
```

I've tried sorting the db by `creation_date`, but it still seems to have the wrong output. Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For this input:

```
+---+-------+----------+
|ids|name   |dates     |
+---+-------+----------+
|123|Jack   |2022-07-07|
|123|Mike   |2022-07-22|
|123|Someone|2022-01-01|
|123|Else   |2022-09-09|
|123|Lust   |2022-05-01|
+---+-------+----------+
```

these lines:

```
ds1
  .orderBy(col("dates").desc)
  .groupBy("ids").agg(collect_list("name").as("alias"))
```

give this result:

```
+---+---------------------------------+
|ids|alias                            |
+---+---------------------------------+
|123|[Else, Mike, Jack, Lust, Someone]|
+---+---------------------------------+
```

I think this is what you are looking for (I populated the dataset with more rows just for testing purposes).